# What is the history of the term "Dungeon Master's Screen"?

Tags: history-of-gaming, terminology

The question [What's the name of cardboard wall DMs use to hide their part of table?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69640/whats-the-name-of-cardboard-wall-dms-use-to-hide-their-part-of-table) has a fairly clearcut answer--"X Master's Screen," where X is "Game" or "Dungeon" depending on the speaker, the game being played, and possibly other regional and/or cultural factors.

[The Wikipedia article on the subject linked from the other question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeon_Masters_Screen) gives a quick history of TSR products called "Dungeon Masters/Master's Screen"s, from the late '70s onwards.  The first such made by TSR was released with, or shortly after, the first *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons* (often retconned as "D&D 1e") books.  I started playing tabletop RPGs around that time, and I remember the product having, on the DM side, a straightforward reprinting of a number of useful tables selected from the *Player's Handbook* and the *Dungeon Master's Guide* but mostly from the latter.  I also clearly remember the art on the "outside" facing the players of the edition of the screen I saw most often--the fat, grinning demonic idol also pictured on the cover of the first few printings of the *AD&D Player's Handbook*:

[image]

I'm calling attention to the art here just because it may jog others' memories.  I'm interested in knowing whether TSR coined the term "DM's Screen," which then (at least in my gaming circles, for what it's worth) became a universal term for that accessory, regardless of what game system was actually being played.  Or were there already similar products from other publishers on the market (or were people making homebrew versions) and TSR just used the prevailing jargon?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [Judge's Shield](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/49524/judges-shield) (1977) predates the [Dungeon Master's Screen](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/46054/dungeon-masters-screen) by about two years, give or take some months. (That the Judge's Guild got to this first is not surprising, as Gygax infamously told them that nothing but rules would sell, and the Judge's Guild was fated to prove him wrong.) So the term “shield” was established before the term “screen”, and still has minority currency today.

The [Referee Screen](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/49348/referee-screen) (1979) for *Traveller* has the same vintage as the DM's Screen and is the only other data point before the 80s begin. It's unclear which was published first that year and therefore which one coined the term “screen”, but together with their two popular games — D&D and Traveller — they certainly had a large enough combined audience to establish the term “screen” in common usage over the the term “shield”, and likely TSR's audience alone would have been enough to establish the term as definitive. (Judge's Guild material, although designed for use with D&D and acclaimed at the time, was not “official” and that would have prevented a lot of play groups that didn't stray from TSR-branded material from being exposed to the alternate term.)

The history isn't very interesting, unfortunately. The only reason we have more than one word for it is because “shield” enjoyed first-to-market advantage in establishing mindshare enough to not be completely destroyed by the TSR juggernaut's adoption and promulgation of the term “screen.”

The “GM Screen” variation, as noted in [the other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69640/whats-the-name-of-cardboard-wall-dms-use-to-hide-their-part-of-table)'s answer, is merely a variation of the term that follows the separate trend of the hobby adopting “game master” as a non-trademarked, non-D&D-specific term, whether out of a hobbyist's need for precision or a publisher' need to avoid legal trouble. The term “GM screen” therefore doesn't have much of an interesting history of its own. You can see “GM screens” in a few early items:

- The Morrow Project's [Game Masters Shield and Reference Tables](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/55870/game-masters-shield-and-reference-tables) (1980)
- The [Star Trek Gamemaster's Kit](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/57686/star-trek-gamemasters-kit) (1983) including a “Gamemaster's Screen”
- Avalon Hill publishing the [RuneQuest Games Master's Screen](http://rpggeek.com/rpgitem/82942/runequest-games-masters-screen) (1989) for RQIII

Comment: I just noticed in the Wikipedia entry for [Top Secret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Secret_(role-playing_game)#Top_Secret_.28original_edition.29) that TSR continued the tradition by publishing an "Administrator's Screen" in 1982.

Comment: Yes, I don't think they ever changed terminology after picking "screen."

Answer (score 14):

Before computers co-opted "screen" for their monitors, it meant [a folding separator made out of panels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folding_screen).

[image: An item of furniture made out of three tall, hinged panels. The folding of the panels allows it to stand on its feet.].

The DM's screen is a folding separator made out of panels—cardboard, not wood, but same purpose and general construction.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question. (The question is not asking why it's called a screen.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think the point he is dancing around is that DM Screen is not a coin-able name, it is a very general description of the product. And therefore no one can be said to have invented it. Though if he included a sentence to that effect if would make it a lot more clear.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski That would make for a more substantial answer that's on-point, yes. (@ Tigt: There's an edit button, should you agree and want to revise your answer.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie This seems like the correct answer for the question title, which is asking for the history of the *term*, which would be where it came from. After reading your excellent answer and rereading the question it's clearer that they wanted to know how that term came to be universally *accepted*, not where it came from.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I couldn't tell for sure whether he was asking about the industry history or the etymology, so I added the latter just in case. (Your answer covered the first one.)